# Is there a rationale for these nested interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, nested

I have inherited some Java code that has this:

```
interface PairDeviceCallbacks extends BasePresenter { 
    interface View extends BaseView { 
    // declare some methods
    }
    void onDeviceClicked( ... )
}
```

`Class1 implements PairDeviceCallbacks`, and `Class2 implements PairDeviceCallbacks.View`. I don't understand why it was structured this way, in particular why have the nested interface. Why not simply two separate top-level interfaces? Is there any reason to add this complexity?

Comment: In what way is the nested interface more complex than having two separate top-level interfaces?

Comment: Could be a organization thing on the part of the other developer.  Think about SomeOtherInterface.View etc.. and to keep things straight and give the appearance of ownership, they would know to always use the .View even if they had completely different methods.

Comment: It smells like a C++ coder trying to write namespace like scopes in Java.

Answer (score 1):

An interface must be implemented by someone else. Hence it is often used as **requirements** *(parameter class)*. It could well that the outer interface needs to do things on something of the inner interface (defining the required methods).

If that is very specific to the outer class/interface, then one could keep it as a nested interface.

The other usage of an interface is to specify **services** delivered *(return results)*. It could well be that the outer class gives a method that yields a very specific object. Such a specific interface can be nested too.

So how specific such an interface is, determines whether the interface has a right to be an independent one. Inner interfaces serve as list of requirements needed or list of services offered.

---

***(Invented) Example***

```
interface ChangeListener {
    interface ChangeEvent {
        Object getSource(); // Requirement: required functionality.
        Object getOldValue();
        Object getNewValue();
    }
    void onChange(ChangeEvent event); // Service: served/provided functionality.
}

// A library creator may add handling of colors:
public class ColorChangeEvent implements ChangeEvent {
    ColorChangeEvent(Object source, Color color) { ... }
    Object  getSource() { ... }
    Color getColor() { .... }
}

// An API user may only need to subclass ChangeListener:
add(new ChangeListener() { ... });
```

Here one would almost expect generics, or a ColorChangeListener.
Interfaces were used for possible various class hierarchies.

---

For callbacks nowadays lambdas appear more often, replacing too specific interfaces just giving one single method: `Consumer<List<Good>>` and such.

Nested classes have still other reasons. A non-static inner class has access to the outer instance. Consider an outer container class like Book and inner classes like Chapter that thus has access to the book's table of content and such.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by an interface is "often used as requirements (parameter class)". Could you elaborate a bit? And going back to my original question, I thought it was odd that one class implemented the outer interface while a different class implemented the inner one. Had never seen this before.

Comment: I have added a bit artificial example, which shows different actors implementing both interfaces. However I admit I have rarely seen both being interfaces.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, having nested interfaces has two benefits. first being that it allows us to group interfaces that are related to one another and also in a way enhances *encapsulation*. I.e, we can only call the nested interface by using the outer interface or class in the same package.

Comment: This is not what "encapsulation" means.

Comment: did i say that's what encapsulation means? _**"and also in a way"** enhances encapsulation_ . i'll let you define what _**"in a way"**_ means.

Comment: Why can we only call the nested interface by using the outer interface? Other than it being package-private, what prevents us from using it from any other class in the same package? Remember, interfaces don't have state, so nested interfaces are implicitly `static`, since they don't (can't) refer to instance of the outer type.

Comment: The way to group related things is packaging them